# Security: Hosting an Ionic App for Desktop Browsers

Tags: angularjs, security, ionic-framework

I have developed an Ionic App. Now i want to give users which are visiting my website with a chrome desktop browser the possibility to try the app.

I would like to host the www directory on a public node server. But because Ionic / Angular is running on the client I fear that it is possible to download the full source code of the app. What can i do against that and do you have other objections against my plans?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: First: Never serve the source code. Always minify and concat your files. Second: Don't generate sourceMaps either. Last but not least - use **different** API keys for the web version so in case of abuse you can simply take them off. There is not much else you can do besides removing some critical functionality from the web version.

Comment: Hi - Thanks a lot for your help!